# packet goes up input chain instead of being forwarded

Tags: iptables, ip-routing, policy-routing

I am trying to see if i can forward traffic through a loopback interface. The primary reason for me to do this is to see if I can force a route lookup as the packet traverses through the loopback interfaces. I have some ebpf hooks that NATs and marks packets that I need to be routed differently based on marks and src IPs. I am just experimenting at the moment, and this question is only to better understand how routing works for packets going through the loopback interfaces.

I have a routing rule to route anything coming from say eth0's IP going to 8.8.8.8 to be routed to the loopback interface lo.
I have another routing rule to route anything coming from lo going to 8.8.8.8 to be routed through the eth1 interface.

I then do a ping using eth0's IP to 8.8.8.8 and this does not work. I then added a iptables rule to TRACE the packet. The routing rules I have are

```
routing rules:
> ip rule show
0: from all lookup local
90: from all iif lo lookup 19
97: from 10.10.100.29 lookup 20
32766: from all lookup main
32767: from all lookup default
> ip route add default via 127.0.0.1 table 20
> ip route add default via 172.16.100.1 table 19
```

When I do a ping using source 10.10.100.29 to 8.8.8.8, I see the following in the iptables trace.

```
PACKET: 2 c11de1cf IN=lo LOOPBACK SRC=10.10.100.29 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=84 TOS=0x0 TTL=64 ID=16089DF
 TRACE: 2 c11de1cf raw:PREROUTING:rule:0x5:CONTINUE  -4 -t raw -A PREROUTING -i lo -j TRACE
 TRACE: 2 c11de1cf raw:PREROUTING:return:
 TRACE: 2 c11de1cf raw:PREROUTING:policy:ACCEPT
 TRACE: 2 c11de1cf mangle:PREROUTING:return:
 TRACE: 2 c11de1cf mangle:PREROUTING:policy:ACCEPT
 TRACE: 2 c11de1cf mangle:INPUT:return:
 TRACE: 2 c11de1cf mangle:INPUT:policy:ACCEPT
```

As you can see the packet has a destination of 8.8.8.8, incoming interface is lo, but it goes up the INPUT chain, instead of a FORWARD chain (8.8.8.8 is not an IP on the host).

Is there an assumption that anything coming through the loopback interface is meant for local consumption?

I have looked at this [Forward packet from loopback interface based on routing table](https://serverfault.com/questions/1043729/forward-packet-from-loopback-interface-based-on-routing-table), and what I am trying to achieve is similar to the other post, but that post does not address why the packet goes up the input chain.